# Editable dataTable response Format

Tags: jquery, servlets, datatables

I am using datatable and datatable editable plugin for inline editing ...
I called the servlet on the request to update...the data updated correctly..but the thing is the response sent from the servlet showed as alert...

My code as follows:

```
        $('#tablename').dataTable().makeEditable({
sUpdateURL: "servletname ,

     "aoColumns": [
                   null,
                   {
                   },
                   {
                       indicator: 'Saving Browser...',
                       tooltip: 'Click to edit browsers',
                       type: 'text',
                       onblur: 'cancel',
                       submit:'Save changes',
                       fnOnCellUpdated: function(sStatus, sValue, settings){
                           alert("as"+sValue);
                           alert("(Cell Callback): Cell is updated with value " + sValue);
                       }
                   }
                 ]                     


});
```

The function,

```
fnOnCellUpdated: function(sStatus, sValue, settings)
```

not get called when the ajax response received.

So how should i make the response to call the function?

Comment: did you server side return a good response ? the updateValue with good headers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case there is no need to send specific response...Send the data which is updated as the response it will get updated automatically if the updation not failed..